# (gphoto2) proper syntax for deleting files

Tags: ubuntu

Having some problems simply trying to delete files using gphoto2 from an MTP-PTP device. I'm in Ubuntu-Mate.

http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html

If I list files using `gphoto2 --list-files` I get

> There is no file in folder '/'. There is no file in folder
>   '/store_00020002'. There is no file in folder '/store_00020002/DCIM'.
>   There is 1 file in folder '/store_00020002/DCIM/100PHOTO'.
>
> #1     FOO_0008.MP4               rd 83232 KB video/mp4 There is 1
>   file in folder '/store_00020002/DCIM/Camera'.
>
> #2     20161222_130348.jpg        rd   604 KB image/jpeg There are 2
>   files in folder '/store_00020002/SYSTEM'.
>
> #3     Device.xml                 rd     1 KB application/x-unknown
>
> #4     license.txt                rd   199 KB text/plain

In my case the file number is 1 and I issue

```
gphoto2 -d 1
```

which returns the following error

> ```
> *** Error ***   There are no files in folder '/'.
> *** Error (-2: 'Bad parameters') ***
> ```

Perhaps i am interpreting the usage incorrectly?

> Usage: gphoto2 [-?qvalLnPTDR] [-?|--help] [--usage] [--debug]
>           [--debug-loglevel=STRING] [--debug-logfile=FILENAME] [-q|--quiet]
>           [--hook-script=FILENAME] [--stdout] [--stdout-size] [--auto-detect]
>           [--show-exif=STRING] [--show-info=STRING] [--summary] [--manual]
>           [--about] [--storage-info] [--shell] [-v|--version]
>           [--list-cameras] [--list-ports] [-a|--abilities] [--port=FILENAME]
>           [--speed=SPEED] [--camera=MODEL] [--usbid=USBIDs] [--list-config]
>           [--list-all-config] [--get-config=STRING] [--set-config=STRING]
>           [--set-config-index=STRING] [--set-config-value=STRING] [--reset]
>           [--keep] [--keep-raw] [--no-keep]
>           [--wait-event=COUNT, SECONDS, MILLISECONDS or MATCHSTRING]
>           [--wait-event-and-download=COUNT, SECONDS, MILLISECONDS or MATCHSTRING]
>           [--capture-preview] [--show-preview] [-B|--bulb=SECONDS]
>           [-F|--frames=COUNT] [-I|--interval=SECONDS] [--reset-interval]
>           [--capture-image] [--trigger-capture] [--capture-image-and-download]
>           [--capture-movie=COUNT or SECONDS] [--capture-sound]
>           [--capture-tethered=COUNT, SECONDS, MILLISECONDS or MATCHSTRING]
>           [--trigger-capture] [-l|--list-folders] [-L|--list-files]
>           [-m|--mkdir=DIRNAME] [-r|--rmdir=DIRNAME] [-n|--num-files]
>           [-p|--get-file=RANGE] [-P|--get-all-files] [-t|--get-thumbnail=RANGE]
>           [-T|--get-all-thumbnails] [--get-metadata=RANGE] [--get-all-metadata]
>           [--upload-metadata=STRING] [--get-raw-data=RANGE]
>           [--get-all-raw-data] [--get-audio-data=RANGE] [--get-all-audio-data]
>           [-d|--delete-file=RANGE] [-D|--delete-all-files]
>           [-u|--upload-file=FILENAME] [--filename=FILENAME_PATTERN]
>           [-f|--folder=FOLDER] [-R|--recurse] [--no-recurse] [--new]
>           [--force-overwrite] [--skip-existing]

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
gphoto2 -f /store_00020002/DCIM/100PHOTO -d 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me,

```
gphoto2 -f /store_00020001/DCIM/100CANON -d 41-90
```

This worked. (deleted from range 41 to 90)

You can obtain the folder structure with

```
gphoto2 -l /
```

And apply the delete command accordingly.

Comment: To delete all files in the directory, you can use `gphoto2 -f /store_00020001/DCIM/100CANON -D`. Sadly, I think we always have to specify the correct directory containing the images. Hope the directory names don't change 